How to sort records ascending using sqlite.net
I've got listview in xamarin forms. Which contains sqlite.net. I did something like this:
 var sorted = data.OrderBy(x => x.DatesRecords)
                  

How to use the metod above in sqlite net

use OrderBy
var query = db.Table<MyTable>().OrderBy(x => x.Date);

